# Android - auto redirect to new activity

Tags: android

I have a scenario when need to redirect to new activity automatically when the next user perform an action.

I need some idea, logic and suggest to find the best way to do it.

In more details.

This is like a bidding app. Where multiple service providers apply to the one job request.

User types: 
Customer and Provider

The customer will select one of the bidder and hire him after completing the payment process (via braintree/paypal)

The system will send notification to the service provider that he won the project.

> What I want is to redirect both of the Users. Customer and Service
>   Provider to be redirected automatically to the Current Job Activity
>   which will have google map and job details.

I know it can be done using notification click but I want it to be redirect automatically.

Can anyone please help me to share some idea or logic to perform such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of notification click you can automatically go into other activity once you receive the notification 
`String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification"`

```
in onResume  

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( this ).registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter( Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION ) );
```

in  onPause

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance( this ).unregisterReceiver( receiver );




 private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
        {
            if ( intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION ) )
            {

                runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                       Intent i=new Intent (CurrentActivity.this,NavigateActivity.class)
                       startActivity(i);

                    }
                } );
            }
        }
    };
```